# Rotated div. Using offscreen slideIn animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions, transform

i have a div which i rotate and place it offscreen.
Now if the user scrolls down the page, i add a animation class from Animate.css
This works all fine. But the rotation transform is lost.

This is my code:

```
...
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
...

<div id="backToTop" class="animated">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

#backToTop {
    display: none;
    background-color: #3b7aad;
    height: 324px;
    width: 324px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -234px;
    right: -234px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    color: #000;
}

   $(document).ready(function() {
      var backToTop;
      function yScroll() {

        backToTop = document.getElementById('backToTop');
        yPos = window.pageYOffset;

        if (yPos > 200) {
          $('#backToTop').stop(true, true).removeClass('slideOutDown');
          $('#backToTop').stop(true, true).addClass('slideInUp');
          $('#backToTop').stop(true, true).show();
        } else {
          $('#backToTop').stop(true, true).removeClass('slideInUp');
          $('#backToTop').stop(true, true).addClass('slideOutDown');
        }

      }
      window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
    });
```

I made a demo on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9L73g5jh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I had to add a wrapper around my rotated div.

Here is an working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/9L73g5jh/6/

```
<div id="backToTopWrapper" class="animated">
   <div id="backToTop">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</div>

#backToTopWrapper {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -234px;
    right: -234px;
}
```